# How to creat only object file without executable?

Tags: object, makefile

I am trying to create an object file through a make file which will be called in another script.

The following is my make file for creating an object file.

```
SOURCE_CK = ../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/
SOURCES_f77 = $(SOURCE_CK)density.f 
#TARGET = 
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES_f77:.f=.o)
COMPILE = f77
.f.o :
$(COMPILE) -o $*.o -c $*.f
#$(TARGET) : $(OBJECTS)
#   $(COMPILE)  $(OBJECTS) -o $@
#del :
#   /bin/rm $(OBJECTS)
```

When I run the above script, the following error gets generated.

```
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Now I know I have to make some modification with TARGET but not sure where to start or how to modify the target.

Again, my goal is to run the script and generate `density.o` file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

GNU Make has built-in rules for making fortran object files from sources, and fortran programs from object files, see https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Catalogue-of-Rules.html

Your makefile can therefore be condensed into just the following:

```
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
```

Should you want to generate just the object, you can even do that without a makefile:

```
# make density.o from a sourcefile
make density.o
```

Note the built-in rules put the object files next to the source files (unless using VPATH etc etc, more about that in the manual), so you'd call it like

```
make ../SOURCES_COUNTERFLOW/density.o
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It worked just by using `make density.o`. Actually I am running some old fortran code created a decade ago. So, if this simple, then do you have any guess why they have created such complex makefile?

Comment: @MohammedNiyasdeen Great news! Could be their make version(s) back in the day didn't support this. Or not having proper makefile training (you get a long way reading the manual once...)